# When if ever was the C language 'int' size altered from the host machine word (register) size into a literal 32 bit size?

Tags: c, compilers

From the earliest K&R reference manuals I read, 'int' was synonymous with machine word and it seemed to raise adverse reactions in various user domains. With the UNIX crowd, they minimally required an MMU(Note *1) so the word had to be 32bits at least to do memory management without segmentation overhead such as we saw with 16bit WinTel memory models (tiny, large, huge etc), so the UNIX machines started with 32bits as a minimum for the preferred flat address space.

But that did not define the C int. I also note that the DB crowd have had a preference for immutable storage specifications, so perhaps they too shunned the semantic int for an imperative one.

The reason I ask is that I notice this sudden appearance of an access barrier where manufactured storage disks easily exceed 2TB which but is pegged by the 'long int's stuck on 32 bit 'int's. But the C int specification should not have forced the 32bit word size that now makes the 32bit semantic incapable of implementing 4TB disk access (by mere recompile) to that of 64bit native word machines?

So if there does exist an explicit standard where 'int' is mandated to 32 bits does anyone know its origins (ANSI? IEEE? POSIX? OTHER? etc) and the motivation for that dramatic change from the K&R specification?

If the 32bit standard was made 'pragmatically' then it would surely be equivalent to that other 640K limit which we once lived to regret.

Feedback is pointing towards pragmatism thus far, for instance the Win64 (Answer by @ssokolow):
In addition to the reasons give on that web page, another reason is that doing so avoids breaking persistence formats. For example, part of the header data for a bitmap file is defined by the following structure:

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
        DWORD      biSize;
        LONG       biWidth;
        LONG       biHeight;
        WORD       biPlanes;
        WORD       biBitCount;
        DWORD      biCompression;
        DWORD      biSizeImage;
        LONG       biXPelsPerMeter;
        LONG       biYPelsPerMeter;
        DWORD      biClrUsed;
        DWORD      biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, FAR *LPBITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

If a LONG expanded from a 32-bit value to a 64-bit value, it would not be possible for a 64-bit program to use this structure to parse a bitmap file.

And the Amdahl 64 = 32x2 comment given by @ faddenon on the experience of bridging the large double jump from 32 to 64. I give a similar current Redhat/CentOS 8 file access structure that has hidden 32bit ints all over (man statx; from man inode):

```
   struct statx {
       __u32 stx_mask;        /* Mask of bits indicating
                                 filled fields */
       __u32 stx_blksize;     /* Block size for filesystem I/O */
       __u64 stx_attributes;  /* Extra file attribute indicators */
       __u32 stx_nlink;       /* Number of hard links */
       __u32 stx_uid;         /* User ID of owner */
       __u32 stx_gid;         /* Group ID of owner */
       __u16 stx_mode;        /* File type and mode */
       __u64 stx_ino;         /* Inode number */
       __u64 stx_size;        /* Total size in bytes */
       __u64 stx_blocks;      /* Number of 512B blocks allocated */
       __u64 stx_attributes_mask;
                              /* Mask to show what's supported
                                 in stx_attributes */

       /* The following fields are file timestamps */
       struct statx_timestamp stx_atime;  /* Last access */
       struct statx_timestamp stx_btime;  /* Creation */
       struct statx_timestamp stx_ctime;  /* Last status change */
       struct statx_timestamp stx_mtime;  /* Last modification */

       /* If this file represents a device, then the next two
          fields contain the ID of the device */
       __u32 stx_rdev_major;  /* Major ID */
       __u32 stx_rdev_minor;  /* Minor ID */

       /* The next two fields contain the ID of the device
          containing the filesystem where the file resides */
       __u32 stx_dev_major;   /* Major ID */
       __u32 stx_dev_minor;   /* Minor ID */
   };
```

No culprits yet, but I suspect IEEE the 'real' pragmatists.

*1) NetBSD which claims portability onto anything requires it to have an MMU

Comment: What does the 2TiB limit have to do with the size of `int` in C?

Comment: I'm not for example a UNIX internals person by any stretch of the imagination, but their access keys are 'long int' which by C standard, double 'int'

Comment: Those comments about mmu and 32 bit are wrong. I use a real Unix from 77 that’s real mode, 16 bit

Comment: C still does not say what size int is. Just the relationship of the sizes of short, int and long

Comment: The amount of data that’s addressable on a drive isn’t determined by the C standard, it’s determined by the standard defining the protocol used to access the drive (SCSI, SATA etc.) and that doesn’t use C data types, it specifies the number of bits to use. Current addressing schemes on ATA-based standards use 48 bits.

Comment: There's quite a few 'real times' that spin their own memory management or file storage, but I recall explicitly reading either Sys7 or BSD (or perhaps even Linux) that 32 was the minimum to implement stock re-entrant multi user multi task unix.

Comment: Re, "manufactured storage disks", @StephenKitt addresses the _hardware_ aspect of that (i.e., what you need to know if you're writing device drivers), but If you're writing user-mode application code in C or in C++, and if your code needs to know byte offsets within a file, then you should store those in `size_t` variables.

Comment: I remember back in 1991, Amdahl's UNIX implementation (UTS) was in a bit of an awkward state because it had calls with 64-bit file offsets before POSIX defined calls with `off_t`, and the implementations didn't quite match up (e.g. Amdahl's `fseek` took a 64-bit position even when `long` was 32-bit). Nothing was decided based on the width of `int`. (Or `size_t`, which is used for transfer counts, not file offsets.) This was a pretty forward-looking thing at the time -- people used 32-bit values back then because 64-bit values seemed absurdly large.

Comment: Afaik the C standard only describes sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) < sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long int), or some similar.

Comment: This is taking me back to erstwhile quibbles. Then (K&R), sizeof was manifestly an operator and not a function and the parens were syntactic sugar for human readers. Are the parens now mandated into sizeof?

Comment: @MKhomo: Sizeof may be used with a type, a value, or an lvalue.  Use with a type requires parentheses.

Comment: OK. loosely, more like a cast operation rather than function call

Comment: I think your assumption is off, `int` even today does not have to be 32 bits.

Comment: **sizeof** is very definitely an operator; it says so in the spec.  It's a funny sort of operator in that as well as being applied to an expression, it can be applied to a type.  The type is parenthesized, as it would be in a cast.

Comment: @ Mark Ransom, I would defer veracity of 32bit arithmetic to the keepers of various OS kernels. The >2TiB blindspot is a live and frustrating phenomenon, not a mere assumption on my part. Just looking at that CentOS stat struct I see plenty lowest common denominators and highest common multiples of 32 in their file access arithmetic. CentOS incidentally does see all 4TiBs, but only by itself (bootloader!)

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the 'statx' example - there is not a single **int** in it.  In fact, what it demonstrates, by avoiding **int**, is that there is no language requirement on the size of **int**.   That structure can be realized on any system that has some 32-bit unsigned integer type and some 64-bit  unsigned integer type (maybe **long** and **long long**); typedefs handle the rest.

Comment: My point that seems to be getting lost is that some resources, could, following the spirit of the k&r int, in cases with no natural limit to define or impose like 'disk', could be specified via int, which naturally evolves with prevalent technology mix. The CentOS stat struct has (which does read 4TiB) obviously leapfrogged the __u32 (I omit bootloader detail etc here) barrier by resorting to __u64 size multipliers, and the same  exercise shall need to get done next time when the popular hard-coded 'uintXX's change size. Surely one does not need to see the bland 'int' to know what's happening?

Comment: It still seems to me you've got it backwards. In cases I've had to decide, I figure out how many bits I'll need (= how many things will exist), multiply by some fudge-factor to future-proof it, and **finally** figure out how to represent that in a given language, compiler, platform.

Comment: @MKhomo: That was a real struggle years ago, when hard drives passed 2GiB, because 2GiB was the biggest value that fit in an `int` on x86 machines. `unsigned int` worked for up to 2GB. I still don't know why you're talking about 2TiB.

Comment: Perhaps by demonstrating  the following on the machine I have handy (CentOS8), uname -a: "Linux C4-E9-84-02-DA-ED 4.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 03:54:29 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". Last night I installed gcc and clang to compile my very old portable 'int-based' arithmetic precision utility, with gcc -dumpfullversion: "8.3.1" to see what it tells me of int on this amd64 machine, and was quite taken aback by the value it reported: +-2^31 (a  value which I picked up decades ago on 32bit m68k architecture BSD, and unchanged still on amd64)!

Comment: This does not quite tally with the spirit of 'int' as 'natural word size' of the architecture.

Comment: At the time I was actively maintaining that arithmetic precision utility I recall the ultrasparc Solaris 2's gave the +-2^63 values, but I have not spun up those old large pizza boxes in more than 10 years and I will not vouch to that definitively at the moment.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck, to answer your question, a 64bit register would presumably be able to address the current stock of spindles in the market which can all hold more than 2TiB, and the x86 2GB style pain which FAT32 helped to ease then has been resurgent in unix-like platforms but at the 2TiB range.

Comment: Note that the PDP-11, the machine UNIX was originally developed for, later had an MMU with 8 kB pages and 16 bit pointers and a 16 bit `int` type.  You do not need 32 bit for an MMU.

Comment: Thanx for the clarification. I am now racking my recollection and seem to remember the mmu prescript I raised as having come out of NetBSD who wanted an mmu within the chipset as pre-requisite for porting their NetBSD onto. This is all from vague recollection and I could stand further correction. At that time, just about all similar unices were already 32bit and smaller sizes were not contemplated.

Comment: I've added to GitHub the precision utility I referred to (https://github.com/mtkAtGH/apax.git) for anyone else to try out their compiler against its old K&R source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What should be emphasized more because it is perhaps unexpected is that **the C standard and POSIX differ** in their requirements for the value range of an `int`. Specifically and importantly, **C never mandated 32 bit `int` sizes.** The reason for the discrepancy may be in the different assumptions each standard can make about the hardware.

C is used for a wide variety of programming tasks. Importantly, because it compiles directly to machine code and does not need a huge runtime, it is the language of choice for programming small embedded systems and microcontrollers, often with *freestanding implementations:* Such systems don't have an operating system, obviously no shell, no processes etc. The requirements the language imposes on C implementations running on such small hardware cannot be too restrictive or they would be broken all the time and hence be useless.

A publicly available [ISO C standard draft from 2007](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), for example, specifies in §5.2.4.2.1

> [The] implementation-defined values [from limits.h] shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

The "minimal maximum" for `int` is then given as

> — maximum value for an object of type int
>
> INT_MAX **+32767**     // 2<sup>15</sup> - 1

By contrast, a POSIX system runs an operating system kernel with *nix-like features (multi-user, multi-tasking among them), provides an elaborate command shell etc. Clearly this requires a much more capable hardware. Which is presumably why the [current POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) mandates **at a minimum** 32 bit integers:

> {INT_MAX}
> Maximum value for an object of type int.
>
> **[CX]** [Option Start] Minimum Acceptable Value: **2 147 483 647**

The ["CX"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#CX) marks this requirement as an extension to the C standard:

> [CX] [Option Start] Extension to the ISO C standard [Option End]
> The functionality described is **an extension to the ISO C standard.** Application developers may make use of an extension as it is supported on all POSIX.1-2017-conforming systems.
> [...]
>
> Where additional semantics apply to a function or header, the material is identified by use of the CX margin legend.

Answer (score 55):

The C standard of the language doesn't mandate a 32-bit `int`. It defines

`sizeof(char)` = 1

and

`sizeof(long long)` ≥ `sizeof(long)` ≥ `sizeof(int)` ≥ `sizeof(short)` ≥ `sizeof(char)`

It also mandates that the constant in `limits.h` are at least the values given below

```
#define CHAR_BIT 8
#define CHAR_MAX UCHAR_MAX or SCHAR_MAX
#define CHAR_MIN 0 or SCHAR_MIN
#define INT_MAX +32767
#define INT_MIN -32767
#define LONG_MAX +2147483647
#define LONG_MIN -2147483647
#define LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807
#define LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807
#define MB_LEN_MAX 1
#define SCHAR_MAX +127
#define SCHAR_MIN -127
#define SHRT_MAX +32767
#define SHRT_MIN -32767
#define UCHAR_MAX 255
#define USHRT_MAX65535
#define UINT_MAX 65535
#define ULONG_MAX 4294967295
#define ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615
```

This means that `int` can be 16 bit or 64 bit, there's no requirement for 32 bit.

As far as I know, POSIX doesn't go beyond that requirement. The only thing that POSIX mandates is that pointer (including function pointer) can be converted to `long` and back. This is required for shared objects (dynamic libraries).

The standard ISO/IEC 9899:1999 aka C99 can be consulted here
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf
There are newer standards (C11) but C99 is imho more relevant.

Comment: Some old computer that were K&R would not be conformant. For example Megamax-C for the Atari ST defined `short` as being 8 bit wide. This would violate the SHRT_MAX requirment for example.

Comment: Some embedded C compiler, notably for TI DSP processors have all types, from `char` to `long` be 32 bit wide and still are conformant.

Comment: No. Chapter 6.2.6.2  constraints would make it unworkable.
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: POSIX SUSv2 does go beyond that requirement by mandating that `int` must have [at least 32 bits](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16366/1981). Later POSIX also requires that `CHAR_BIT == 8`

Comment: @ OmarL, I think floats at sub-int ranges point to IEEE, at least stylistically; and I think the bit length type defs common to structs also find their inspiration in IEEE float specification.

Comment: @OmarL No, that's not what Patrick is saying. These are just the value ranges. The standard also describes what operations there are and what their semantics are.

Comment: I have ANSI X3.159-1989 on paper, and the same INT_MAX (etc) were in effect then.

Comment: @OmarL: `int` has to hold all integer values between -32767 and +32767, so it requires at least 16 bits. But Cray supercomputers did in fact use (larger) float registers to store ints. That was possible because those registers could store -32767.0 to +32767.0 and all integers in between. So `sizeof(int)==4` can still occur when `INT_MAX=32767`.

Comment: @MSalters That is an interesting detail; but I'll note that the register size is not directly related to the value of `sizeof`! (Conceivably it could be smaller in RAM.)

Answer (score 37):

The C standard only requires that the `int` type be at least 16 bits wide. There's no requirement that `int` be 32 bits, though it's a very common implementation choice these days.  An exception would be C compilers targeting 8-bit embedded systems which mostly use a 16-bit `int`.

(Note the C standard specifically requires that `int` be able to hold a value in the range -32,767 to 32,767 inclusive.  There's no requirement that it be able to hold the value -32,768, allowing for sign-magnitude and ones' complement representations.)

The first C compiler was written for Unix running on the PDP-11 and used a 16-bit `int`. So there wasn't a requirement in the Unix world that `int` be 32 bits either. Originally POSIX didn't place any additional requirements on `int` over the C standard, but in 2001 POSIX adopted the Single Unix Specification which requires at least a 32-bit `int` (though still allowing sign-magnitude and ones' complement representations.)  However, unlike Standard C compliance which is commonly claimed by C compilers, very few current operating systems claim to be fully POSIX/SUS-compliant. Most environments that use a 32-bit `int` are doing so voluntarily.

These days, with the exception of certain embedded systems mentioned above, a 32-bit `int` is the universal choice of C implementations.  In the past there have also been C compilers that used a 36-bit `int` (for Honeywell GCOS systems) and a 64-bit `int` (for Cray supercomputers), and of course MS-DOS C compilers used a 16-bit `int`, but these are all long obsolete.

When 64-bit CPUs became a thing, it might have seemed natural for C compilers targeting these CPUs to use a 64-bit `int`, but in practice this would've produced slower code because of the increased data size, while adding additional difficulty in porting software to the CPUs.

Comment: Another example of a C compiler with 36-bit `int`s: kcc, which targets the PDP-10.

Comment: Does POSIX require exactly 32-bit, or *at least* 32-bit `int`?  [@phuclv commented](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/when-if-ever-was-the-c-language-int-size-altered-from-the-host-machine-word-r#comment55086_16353) that it was "at least" in SUSv2.

Comment: Re: keeping 32-bit int for 64-bit machines: indeed, most/all 64-bit ISAs have efficient hardware support for 32-bit operand-size, at least for some common operations (e.g. Alpha), unlike with 16-bit short on 32-bit machines.  (related: [C++ int vs long long in 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39779880))

Comment: @PeterCordes  Yes, I should've said at least 32 bits.

Comment: The biggest practical problem with 64-bit `int` is that the implementation then either has to omit or use a nonstandard type for one of `int8_t`/`int16_t`/`int32_t`, because there are only two standard integral types (`char` and `short`) smaller than `int`.

Answer (score 21):

There is no such requirement in standard C. Traditionally, an int was required to be at least 16 bits, though since the mid-1980s I started to write code as if an int was at least 32 bits, confident I did not intend to support older hardware.

When we moved to 64-bit systems, it was common in some implementations for int to remain at 32 bits, since this eased porting code that had made that assumption.

The first implementation of Unix, and C, was on the PDP-11, a 16-bit machine, so sizeof (int) was 2.  The [first port of Unix](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/bits/Interdata/32bit/unix/univWollongong_v6/miller.pdf), to an Interdata 7/32. made sizeof (int) be 4.

But the question is confused on other matters.

Unix originally ran on PDP-11 (and without an MMU, either - at least until Thompson and Ritchie got an 11/40), which is a 16-bit machine, and int in C was defined as a 16-bit machine word.

None of this is anything to do with file system size limits. 16-bit CPUs could and did support 32-bit file sizes (or larger, but practical concerns may not have made that sensible). 32-bit CPUs could, did, and do support 64-bit file sizes.

There is a potential problem with API defined in C terms.  For example, PDP-11's seek() syscall had to become lseek() when disks could support more than 64K blocks, and an int argument was no longer sufficient.

Windows on 32-bit hardware (the NT family at least) supported 64-bit file sizes, offsets, etc., by the simple expedient of providing two 32-bit arguments to hold a 64-bit value -- either as two actual function arguments, or as a single struct that had two 32-bit members.

Answer (score 16):

If you need a date, then [March 12, 1997](http://www.unix.org/version2/pr.html).  That's when Single UNIX Specification version 2 (aka `UNIX98`) was released. Among other changes to the ISO C standard (via [`limits.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/limits.h.html)), `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` were changed to 2,147,483,647 and -2,147,483,647, respectively (the same as `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN`).  This of course does not mandate a 32-bit int (64-bit ints are compliant) and it doesn't affect the ISO/ANSI C standards.

Comment: I assume this is POSIX? It, as you say, does not mandate a 32bit int, but I cannot see how one can comply without forcing 32 bit signed on ints.(!!) Is this my smoking gun?  (PS: Were there any card-carrying IEEE members on that commitee? heh heh!)

Comment: Changes to the C standard? No, they don't have the authority. Requirements on top of the C standard? Sure, they need and want to guarantee more, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, that's POSIX.  It sets 32-bit as the minimum int size. But anything bigger (36-bits, 64-bits, 128 bits) would also be valid int, so it's not a requirement to be *exactly* 32-bit.

Comment: Perhaps here might be the crux of the matter. Say as of March 12,1997 one implements on a particular architecture a compiler with INT_MIN and INT_MAX using +/- 2^31 as per UNIX98. Then other implementation such as say +-2^63 limits may be UNIX98 compliant, but cannot be admissible concurrently with the first one because they'd be then be contradictory if they were trying to use the same manifest symbol INT_MIN and INT_MAX (unless #ifdef protected for cross-compilation to a different architecture). My concern is not cross-compilation but run-time addressing using int / long references.

Comment: @MKhomo It didn't become POSIX until 2001 when POSIX adopted the SUS as a standard. Previously they were separate standards.

Comment: @MKhomo: Implementations for the classic Macintosh could be configured to treat `int` as either 16 bits or 32 bits, and there was no problem running some programs that use one style of `int` and some that use the other, since each implementation would statically link a copy of the Standard library suitable for the program being built, and programmers writing other libraries would generally use `short` and `long` instead of `int` for anything that would interact with other libraries, thus making the size of `int` irrelevant for calls between separately-compiled functions, except...

Comment: ...when using variadic functions.  While there was no nice way to avoid problems with those, having compilers treat `long` as the Classic-Mac did `int` should have made it practical to have implementations with both size of `long` coexist smoothly on the same system.

Comment: @supercat, I wonder what would happen on such a machine if a kernel-keeper generated two kernel variants using the two differing styles of int, (and of course changing those __u32 types to __uintstyle1 and _uintstyle2 respectively, to not break internal coherence). A minimal build, perhaps file system only? It would certainly decide the issue for me.

Comment: That is needlessly complicated.  Define one kernel interface with the wider API.  Define a user-mode library for use in the narrower case that maps it onto the actual kernel API. A similar approach is used in Windows, whose kernel deals in 16-bit characters (which are not C chars), but which supports a compatibility layer with 8-bit characters for fossilized software that wants to use ASCII, etc.

Comment: @another-dave: I'd regard 16-bit characters as more fossilized than 8-bit.  The only advantage UTF-16 has over UTF-8 is that code designed for UCS-2 can handle UTF-16 text whose code points are all below 0xFFFF without having to care about multi-character code points.  The way Unicode has evolved, however, ended up sacrificing considerable packing density to allow context-insensitive processing, but then adding composite-glyph rules that defenestrate the context-insensitive processing for which packing density had been sacrificed.

Comment: True. UCS-2 was good in 1990, but once we hit the 16-bit barrier, UTF-8 seems best.  UTF-16 is the worst of both worlds. But my comment was an off-topic snipe at people who think that text is "ASCII".

Comment: @another-dave: For most purposes, text should be a string of bytes, where bytes that match the ASCII codes of members of the C character set represent those characters, and other bytes are processed in character-set-agnostic fashion.  When handling text which is intended to be written and processed *primarily* by computers, anything beyond that is more likely to be a hindrance than a help.

Comment: While this is the only answer that tries to give a date, very strictly speaking, it doesn't answer the question. The C standard never asked for 32 bits, what you're referring to is "additional requirements over the C standard that apply to a C compiler for a POSIX-compliant system" - That's something different. Embedded systems, for example, would never strive to be POSIX-compliant, but can still have a ISO-C-compliant compiler.

Answer (score 10):

When C was invented, there was no particular reason why an implementation would want to use a value for `int` which was smaller than a register.  Although the Standard allowed implementations to choose almost any means they wanted to pick the sizes of integer types, the common practice was that, *absent any reason to do otherwise*:

- `char` would be the smallest addressable unit that was at least 8 bits (even platforms with bit-addressable or nybble-addressable storage were required to make all pointers be multiples of `char`).
- `short` would be the smallest practical type that was at least 16 bits.
- `long` would be the smallest practical type that was at least 32 bits.
- `long long`, when supported, would be the smallest practical type that was at least 64 bits.
- `int` would be at least large as `short`, but could be the smallest type of at least 32 bits on platforms that could process such values at about the same speed as smaller ones.

On some platforms like the 68000, 32-bit computations were about 30-50% slower than 16-bit ones, so compilers for that platform often allowed programmers a choice of whether `int` should be 16 or 32 bits.  On platforms where there would be a 2:1 speed difference, `int` would typically be 16 bits, and on those where there was no speed difference or 32-bit math would be faster, `int` would typically be 32 bits, but on the 68000 the speed difference fell right in the middle.

Note that it's often considered desirable to have a standard integer type for each each power-of-two size from 8 bits to 64 bits.  If `int` were 64 bits, there would only be two standard types that were smaller than 64 bits, which wouldn't be enough to have a type available for each of the common object sizes (8, 16, 32).

Comment: I can see now a preference for speed keeping int's at a preferred size at a particular time of implementation. I suppose the same can be said of the compiled image size where N instructions doubled the image size with plenty superfluous bloat.

Comment: @MKhomo ARM Thumb-mode is a contemporary equivalent.

Comment: I must hand it to chip-set  designers for their level of ingenuity. Another comment pointed out alternating int sizes on the 68k motorola chip set I think, possibly now a maxscale brand.

Answer (score 10):

The book "Writing Solid Code" documents an instance where the size of an int changed.  There is a section which noted that (once upon a time) Microsoft's own internal C code sources often hard-coded the value '2' (bytes) instead of writing 'sizeof(int)', under the theory that "... well, we OWN the C compiler -surely our own compiler group wouldn't change something as fundamental as the size of an int!".  They then proceeded to do exactly that.  Broke a lot of code - lots of embarrassment all around *['course that was back in the 80's]*.

Comment: Sounds bizarre, but once I saw the C compiler headers for DOS, coming from BSD UNIX I can sympathise with MS's programmers. It eventually led to name standards police and Hungarian Notation just to maintain sanity. When C++ came along Hungarians mandated they all are little 'm~', and that's become universal and even in Java where class identifiers are big ^[A-Z] with little m's redundant. Later they acquired branded Lattice C as MSC Compiler V6 or something. But that had to have come from Intel engineers.

Comment: But this is just a Microsoft implementation, not "the C language" itself.

Comment: and even within Microsoft, I would suppose that sizeof (int) == 2 on 16-bit systems, and 4 on 32-bit systems.  It's not like they changed the size on a single system.

Comment: @MKhomo It was much earlier that Microsoft rebranded Lattice. According to Wikipedia and one of its sources, MS C v 3.0 was the first version written in-house. Like you, I thought that Microsoft had bought Lattice, but it seems not.

Comment: Also looked at Wikipedia and saw the mention that Lattice C (the brand) is servicing mainly mainframe compilers. I cannot think it not coming out of Intel. And, at some stage Intel was going under over AMD 286 IP and IBM bailed them out. Perhaps that could be how the current Lattice compiler target is mainframe. (Watch for future Java focus on VARCHAR :)

Answer (score 7):

> With the UNIX crowd, they minimally required an MMU so the word had to be 32bits at least to do memory management without segmentation overhead

Not true. The PDP-11 had a 16 bit word size and a 16 bit address size which meant that user space processes were limited to 64 kilobytes. I'm not 100% certain but I think that `int` and `char *` were both 16 bits for C compilers targeted at the PDP-11. The PDP 11 ran Unix just fine.

> But that did not define the C int.

The C `int` was usually but not always selected to be the optimal size for the target processor. I wouldn't say it was a standard but it was an informal "best practice". For example, the Megamax C compiler that I used with my Atari ST had a 16 bit `int` because that was the fastest size on a 68000. It did, however, have a 32 bit pointer size because that was the size of the address registers. That used to cause me all sorts of problems with porting code because a surprising amount of it assumed that `int` and `char *` were the same size.

On the other hand, the more sophisticated and (crucially for me) more expensive Mark Williams C used 32 bits for both `int` and `char *`.

> The reason I ask is that I notice this sudden appearance of an access barrier where manufactured storage disks easily exceed 2TB which but is pegged by the 'long int's stuck on 32 bit 'int's. But the C int specification should not have forced the 32bit word size that now makes the 32bit semantic incapable of implementing 4TB disk access (by mere recompile) to that of 64bit native word machines?

Any limits of that nature would be far more complicated than simply "the size of an `int`". For example, it might be  the size of an `int` times the size of a block or cluster. It really depends on the operating system or the file system, not the compiler. The C definitions of the `stat` structure are not prescriptive, they are descriptive. i.e. as a rule, the OS defines how big a thing is and the C declaration has to match it, not the other way around.

Comment: I fully understand the difficulties you raise, and how headers like limits.h protected portability, interoperability and the rest of it. And I can see how the file systems are  the derterminant and not system primitives of their implementation language. It's more the OS vision. So if I were to think futuristic in a Hurd way, I'd start with an "unlimited.h" resource file where all the things that do not need to have a mandated limit go. These would be provisioned resources mainly, so things like a 640K memory max or disk storage access would not sneak in through internal system structures.

Comment: I think with disks, we're currently in an unusual period where the physics and technology built into Moore's law has outpaced software's ability to guzzle emergent h/w capacity.

Comment: Perhaps the same could be said of 5G bandwidth stuck in the hands of carriers ...

Answer (score 7):

As a couple of people have noted, Unix originally ran on the PDP-11,¹ which had 16-bit pointers and `int`s. The original PDP-11/20, which Unix first ran on, had no MMU, but one was added in the PDP-11/45, which was still 16-bit. By V6, Unix implemented a form of virtual memory by copying entire programs in and out of memory as needed.

(Interesting side-note: [the shell on V1](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/sh.s) had about 350 lines of *assembler* source code. *Large* programs, like the C compiler and the assembler, were split into two executables, which communicated using temporary files. PDP-11 Unix programs were probably *too small* to page! Paging, like 32-bit computing, was introduced by the port of BSD to the VAX.)

Beyond that, [Xenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix) ran on 8086s (with a non-standard MMU, so not 100% IBM-compatible) and 80286s, with a segmented memory architecture and 32-bit pointers but 16-bit `int`s.

That had interesting consequences when passing a literal `0` to a K&R C function taking a pointer (no prototypes back then!), or to a variadic function like `execl`. I think things like the `NULL` symbolic constant come from that background, where an unambiguously pointer-sized `0` was needed.

(According to [DMR](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/1stEdman.html), the original Unix machine had 24KB of memory installed, which is a bit larger than the original IBM PC's 16KB, but less than half of what a 16-bit address space can handle. [This link](https://github.com/jserv/unix-v1/blob/master/notes/machine.txt) says V1 processes had 8KB of 'userspace' memory available to them. Of course, by the 1980s Unix programs had expanded to require a bit more memory!)

¹ Technically Unix development started on the PDP-7, but development moved to the PDP-11 before V1, and long before anything we would recognize as 'Unix' today. (The kernel was rewritten in C [for V4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix#1970s), in 1973, and for ease of development, not for portability yet.) V6 (1975), which was the first widely-distributed Unix, and V7 (1979), which was the common ancestor of all 'modern' Unixes, including the *BSDs, both ran primarily on the PDP-11. (Although by V6 porting efforts to other machines had started.)

Comment: PDP-11 C had 8-bit chars, not 16-bit chars.  Typo?   And the first PDP-11 Unix was on an 11/20, a machine with no MMU. Though I'm not sure at what time C came in.

Comment: AFAICT, the early versions of Unix that ran on the PDP-11/20 required the memory to be expanded to the maximum 28kwords (56kbytes). See https://github.com/jserv/unix-v1/blob/master/notes/machine.txt for a description of the machine that the earliest extant version of Unix run on. It seems the system used 12kwords just for the kernel, and 16kwords were required for the running user space program. By this time, C was already in use. AIUI, C was introduced to the Unix kernel during the rewrite to switch to the PDP-11.

Comment: By 1990 Unix users got a real workstation running some kind of Unix (SunOS/Irix/whatever) depending on what they needed it for.  Those were too expensive for private users, but not uncommon in the university world.

Comment: I should add that in the UK there was a Whitechapel MG, a sun clone whose reason for being was its fully integrated motherboard unlike the Sun's assembled off-the-shelf components into motherboard. The Whitchapel acquired the motherboards from Pacific rim and were very price competitive as they were running the same BSD4.2 as Sun was with equivalent framebuffered 17" monitor. But it's a treacherous market and the MG went belly-up just as they began trying to break the US market. And yes, this was Education market. The UK had decided to pilot UNIX at City and Sterling and I was at City.

Comment: The Whitechapel Sun clone workstation utilised a National Semiconductor ns32000 chip

Comment: @occipita - that link specifically says they had only 24KB of memory on the lab's PDP-11/20. Every source I've read says the V1 kernel was ASM.

Comment: @another-dave+ the _BellLabs_ 11/20 did have memory mapping, though not the 8x8KB x sometimes I/D x K/[S]/U that became standard on 11/40 and up (and then 11/34 and LSI-11/23 and 73) -- [according to dmr (see bottom of page)](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/odd.html) Also to be clear, (all) 11s had 16-bit virtual address and registers, but UNIBUS had 18-bit physical address, even on  models without MMU where 'segment 7' forced the extra 2 bits high so interface boards would work the same as with MMU.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about a standard, but Microsoft chose the LLP64 model for 64-bit Windows, which means that everything except pointers stays as if the processor word size were 32-bit.

Raymond Chen's blog, The Old New Thing, has an [explanation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563) for why they made that choice (which builds on a now-dead link to [this MSDN page](https://web.archive.org/web/20050906103124/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/win64/win64/abstract_data_models.asp)).

(In short, to make 64-bit porting feasible for pre-`uint32_t` code which embeds assumptions about type sizes in its definitions of things like file-formats and binary IPC, and to make it easier for 32-bit and 64-bit builds to be made from a common source during the transition period.)

...and, as Patrick Schlüter pointed out and I forgot to mention, the C standard doesn't really say much more than which types are not allowed to be smaller than which other types.

Comment: I wonder how often making `long` 64 bits offers any real advantage over having programmers use either `int64_t` or `long long` when they want a 64-bit type?  The LLP64 model offers better compatibility with earlier programs than LP64; while LP64 may allow programs to handle larger data sets than LLP64 without modification, I wouldn't trust that expanding the size of `long` would be sufficient to increase the number of items that can be reliably processed by a program that supported two billion items when `long`was 32 bits.

Comment: I was involved with porting application software to Itanium on Windows quite early on, and the Windows headers in the first iteration of the Platform SDK were LP64, not LLP64. The explanation Microsoft gave me was that there was lots of wizard-generated GUI code in customer companies that assumed longs and ints were the same size. It was much easier to change the size of long than to write a tool to sort out code that had been customised after generation.

Comment: @JohnDallman: Prior to the standardization of int32_t, etc. `long` was the closest thing there was to a 32-bit type.  While `int` could be 16 or 32 bits, `long` couldn't, so code assuming `long` was 32 bits would be more widely portable than code making assumptions about the size of any other type.

Comment: @supercat my boss still insists that our coding standards prefer `long` to `int`, because he got burned back when `int` was only 16 bits and he won't forget.  Thankfully we're using a MS compiler that still keeps `long` at 32 bits or we'd have a real mess.

Comment: It's a shame that your boss chose *that* solution, rather than learning about type definitions, @Mark... Maybe he'll learn when `long` changes meaning some day to a 128-bit type?

Comment: @CodyGray: There were two conflicting assumptions made by various programs: (1) that code needing a four-byte type can use `long` for that purpose, or (2) that programs needing a type that can round-trip pointers can use `long` for that purpose.  Of those two assumptions, I would regard the latter as more dubious, since every general-purpose octet-based implementation should be expected to have a 32-bit integer type, but some implementations for 32-bit platforms might not allow pointer round-trips through it.  Code needing to use 32-bit segmented mode on the 80386 without...

Comment: ...putting everything in the same segment, for example, would need to use 48-bit pointers, which the processor could fetch in a single instruction (e.g. `LES ESI,[someplace]`).  Most implementations simply used one segment for everything (and thus didn't bother storing the segment selector) but Intel certainly expected that at least some implementations would use wider pointer types.

Comment: Round-tripping pointers through `long` is indeed dubious, but having `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` be larger than `long` is forbidden by the 1989 C standard. Microsoft forced a change into the 1999 C standard to allow these types to be defined as `long long`, over literally every other committee member's objections. And then, for almost 20 years (specifically until VS2017, iirc) they didn't bother implementing the C99 features that would compensate for breaking all the code that depended on `size_t` being no larger than `long` (like `intmax_t` and `printf("%zu")`). Not That I'm Bitter™.

Comment: @ zwol, Almost missed this subtlety, but it now jumps at me because an earlier comment had suggested long long for the largest 'int' to quell my disquiet. And I guess I'd have to migrate to MSVS for that solution?

Comment: @zwol: The fact that a system uses 64-bit pointers in no way implies that `size_t` nor `ptrdiff_t` couldn't remain 32 bits.  For applications which don't use any *individual* data items larger than 2GiB and don't need to round-trip pointers through `long`, there would be no problem keeping `size_t`, `ptdiff_t`, and `long` all as 32-bit types.

Comment: @supercat Yes, but the Win64 ABI _does_ allow for individual data items larger than 2GB.

Comment: @zwol: There are many situations on the x86 where an application would behave identically on implementation which uses a 32-bit `long` as on one that uses a 64-bit `long`, but the former would run much faster because of the former type's smaller cache footprint.  The right approach for implementations to take would have been to allow users to specify the sizes of `long`, `ptrdiff_t`, and `size_t` so as to best fit their applications' needs.  Even if Windows would allow individual objects larger than 2GiB to be allocated, applications that never *use* any objects that big...

Comment: ...generally wouldn't benefit from having `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` that could accommodate them, but would benefit more from using types with a lower cache footprint.

Comment: @zwol: Even in the days of MS-DOS, where `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` were 16-bit types, there were ways of creating objects more than 65,536 bytes in size.  Using them, however, required non-portable techniques.  Since anything using the Windows API will be *inherently* non-portable, an inability to access super-sized objects in normal fashion isn't necessarily a severe problem.

Comment: Many people moan about the "bad old days" where compilers for the PC distinguished between "near" and "far" pointers, but fail to recognize that (1) programmers that didn't want to worry about such distinctions could use far pointers for everything, but (2) programs that kept the most active parts of their working set within a 64K region and used 16-bit pointers to access it could be much faster than those that used 32-bit pointers for everything.  The same thing would true today, except that nobody seems to remember the performance benefits of segregating near and far pointers.